# omit spaces inside macro

Tags: detokenize

I'm trying to understand why I can get LaTeX to ignore spaces inside text, but when I do the same thing inside a macro, it fails to ignore those spaces.

I use \catcode32=9 to ignore ASCII space chars.  (I've also tried \ignorespaces, but had even less success with that.)  The following MWE illustrates (at least it's as minimal as I can get it, although I've left in a couple \typeout's to help visualize what's going on, and a bunch of comments).

```
\documentclass{report}

%==========gll=========
%Introduce 2-line text-and-gloss:
\gdef\gll#1
  {\bgroup
   \catcode`\^^M=12
   \onesent#1
  }

{\catcode`\^^M=12 \endlinechar=-1 % 12 = other
% Within this block (down to the comment "restore \catcode`\^^M"),
% newline (^^M) is treated as a matchable char for TeX's regex matching.

%==========getwords=========
%Recursively tokenize the input line, outputting each token in an \hbox
% Args:
%    #1=1st token of line, e.g. {\textbf{AAA}}
%    #2=remainder of line, i.e. remaining tokens; empty on final pass
\gdef\getwords#1 #2^^M
   {\typeout{1=#1}%Debug:
    \typeout{2=#2}%Debug:
    \hbox{\catcode32=9X#1X}
    \def\more{#2}
      \ifx\more\empty\let\more=\donewords
      \else\let\more=\getwords
      \fi
    \more#2^^M
   }

%==========donewords=========
%End the recursion
\gdef\donewords#1^^M{}%

%==========twosent=========
%Introduce a space char before the newline
\gdef\onesent#1^^M%
   {\typeout{onesent,1=#1}
    \getwords#1 ^^M%
    \egroup % matches \bgroup in \gloss
   }

} % restore \catcode`\^^M

\begin{document}
Use \textbackslash{}catcode to ignore spaces:

I{\hbox{\catcode32=9\textbf{  AAA } \textbf{ \textit{ aaa  }}}}I

===============

Try same thing inside \textbackslash{}gll; first line has no space in 
source text, while second has leading, intenal and trailing spaces; Xs 
added on left and right for clarity:

\gll \textbf{AAA} \textbf{ AA A }
\end{document}
```

The result looks like
   XAAAX
when I do it in the text, i.e. \catcode32=9 works as I expect it to.  But when I do it inside the macro, it looks like
   X AA A X
i.e. the catcode does nothing.

Motivation: The above code is a much simplified version of what goes on in the Covington macros for glossed interlinear text.  The spaces prevent proper alignment in the output.  Of course one solution is to eliminate the stray spaces in the source code, but for various reasons it's hard to enforce this :-).  I thought surely a programmatic solution would be easy.  Wrong.

Actually, I do have a programmatic solution, which relies on using

```
\spaceskip 1sp
```

(as suggested in another Q/A on this site) in place of the \catcode method. This works, except the ragged2e package breaks it by re-defining

```
\spaceskip 0pt
```

every time the font gets set--and we do re-set the font inside our interlinears (e.g. bolding some stuff).

Tested under pdfLatex in the 2016 TeXLive release (and earlier versions tested with xelatex).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way that catcodes work in LaTeX is quite confusing. The problem you have is that if you define a macro:

```
\def\test#1{
    \catcode` =9\relax 
    % now do some stuff
 }
```

when you call `\test{argument}` the argument is parsed and the catcodes are assigned to the tokens of the argument while expanding `\test` and before any of the code in `\test` is evaluated. The

```
\catcode` =9\relax
```

inside `\test` then occurs after the catcodes have already been assigned to the tokens in the argument.

This is the source of the problem that occurs when using certain environments in macros. For instance, tikz-cd makes `&` into an active character, so if you say `\footnote{\begin{tikzcd}A & B\end{tikzcd}}` the argument to `\footnote` will get parsed when `\footnote` is expanded, and `&` is assigned catcode "alignment character", and then when `\begin{tikzcd}` changes the catcode of `&` to "active" it is too late.

There are a few possible solutions. The less robust solution, which is probably appropriate for your situation, is to define a wrapper command that takes no argument, starts a group and changes the catcode, then calls the inner command which takes an argument. The body of this inner command can immediately end the group because by the time we get there, the arguments have already been assigned their catcodes, so the catcodes don't matter anyways:

```
\gdef\gll{
   \bgroup
   \catcode`\^^M=12\relax
   \catcode`\ =9\relax % This relax is really important
   \onesent
}
\gdef\onesent#1^^M{%
    \egroup
     % Do stuff
}
```

Note the critical `\relax`. Another gotcha is that this approach fails without it. This is because when TeX is looking for a numeric value, it keeps scanning, expanding macros until it sees a token it definitely cannot incorporate into the number. So without the `\relax` it would expand `\getwords@` to check if it has a number as it's first character to incorporate into the catcode. However, this expansion leads to the parsing of the argument and occurs before the catcode assignment actually happens.

The other option is to use `\scantokens`:

```
\gdef\getwords#1 #2^^M{%
    \bgroup
    \catcode`\ =9\relax
    \scantokens{\hbox{X#1X}}%
    \egroup
    % Do some other stuff
}
```

`\scantokens` is an eTeX primitive that detokenizes it's argument and retokenizes it with the current catcodes, thus fixing the problem you have. This would be robust to problems with people wrapping `\getwords` in the argument of another command.

Comment: Is it possible to escape upticks inside of TeX code so you can say something like `\catcode'\ =9\relax` where the ' should be an uptick?

Comment: yes you can do `\catcode\`\ =9\relax` (a backslash before the backtick)

Comment: Yeah, I figured it was a question of when tokenization happened, but I didn't know what to do about that.

Comment: However, I tried the two methods you give, and I can't get them to work.  The first doesn't seem to have any effect, and while the \scantokens method indeed gets rid of the whitespace, it results in the second box being indented, with a leading and trailing 'fl' ligature, like this:

XAAAX
     flXAAAXfl

where the 'fl' appears to be a ligature.  (That's with pdflatex; xelatex is similar, except a box in place of the 'fl', apparently U+DBC2.)  What is this 'fl'?  End of file marker??

Comment: I thought I edited my answer, but apparently I didn't. The problem with the first method as currently explained is that you have to do it in `\gll`. I'll fix it.

Comment: I don't feel like testing this right now, but I strongly suspect that at least part of the problem you are having with `\scantokens` is that you are forgetting that you set the catcode of endline to other. I bet that box you are getting is caused by it printing an endline character. The fix would be to end the group started by `\gll` at the beginning of `\onesent` so the problematic and at-this-point unnecessary catcode of newline is no longer in effect when `\scantokens` happens.

Comment: I have been able to get the \scantokens version, but not the \catcode version, to work.  I'm going to mark this as an answer, thanks!